# How to stop receiving ‘AWS Notification Message’

Tags: amazon-web-services

I’m set up with AWS and for every email that gets generated by my website a subsequent email is fired off by aws with the header:
‘AWS Notification Message’
Is there a way to stop this from happening? It is going to my bounce back email if that helps in anyway. I’m suspecting I may have a setting enabled but I’ve been through much of AWS and can’t figure it out.

Comment: In the email, at the bottom, there is no unsubscribe link?

Comment: If your situation does not match the image from @Mahendra, then please edit your question and provide a sample of the email you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you, and yes there is, I just didn’t pay attention to it. And it worked. It took a day to follow through with the unsubscribe but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a link in the email to unsubscribe it with the below message.

```
"If you wish to stop receiving notifications from this topic, please click or visit the link below to unsubscribe:"
```

Screenshot for your reference.

[image: Screenshot for your reference.]